# How to stream (upload) large amount of data with Requests in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

The module `requests` provides a high level HTTP API. Using `requests` I'd like to send data via HTTP using a POST request. The documentation is very short about this, stating that a "file like object" should be provided without stating clearly what exactly `requests` would expect from that object. I've some binary data, but unfortunately this is generated data and I have *not* a file like object. How could I possibly implement a "file like object" myself that would conform to the expectations of `requests`? The documentation is quite poor in that regard and I wasn't able to clarify this by looking into the source code of `requests` myself. Has anyone done this before using the `requests` API?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a file object, [`files`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) accepts bytes also.

Comment: But if you want to create a file-like object you can use [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o)

Comment: The idea of streaming is to NOT need to load the complete data into memory all at once. But thank you for mentioning `BytesIO` as this will help me in a different matter.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to post bytes. If you want to stream a large file see: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads

Comment: Please. As I said in the question: The documentation is poor in that regard. I don't HAVE a file. I don't know how to use that method as I don't have a file. I'd like to provide a suitable object here but I don't know how to do that as the documentation does not talk about this. Please provide me with some information on how to do that. How exactly do I have to define a class that I can deliver data to that method? That is my question.

Comment: What type of object is it then? I know It's not a file or bytes, but what is it? I can't help if I don't know that.

Comment: Reading your question more carefully I see you're talking about "generated data". If that data is bytes generated from a function, you could use the `data` parameter with a generator, like in this example: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As far as I understood from the source code and the documentation - and I could be wrong in that matter - this is intended for non-binary data. But I'm not sure about that. The example uses strings but I'm not sure, maybe it is limited to strings? The documentation is a bit short on all that. My prototypical implementation is not yet ready to test it but I will give it a try as soon as I can.

Comment: It supports bytes too. I just tested the code (with bytes instead of strings), and it seems to work fine. BTW if you want to test a request you can use http://httpbin.org/anything. It returns a very detailed json response.

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you for this information!

Answer (score 0):

`File-like object` is a standard Python term for an object that behaves like a file. This means that if you have a file, you have a `file-like object` and simply need to pass the file path to `Requests`. If you have a more complex situation you will need to give us a full description of the form of your data so we can help you more explicitly.

EDIT: To address your comment, here is the code to send a binary file to a host using `Requests`.

```
url = 'http://SomeSite/post'
files = {'files': ('mydata', open('mydata', mode='rb'), 'application/octet-stream')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Opening the file with the `Python open` command creates the `file-like object`.

EDIT2: Whenever to open a file on disk you create a file-like object in the process of opening the objects. However, Python supports other object types that act like files. Some examples include the standard `stdin, stdout and stderr`. In addition, pipes can be access using os.pipe and via subprocess.Pipe. These objects behave like files, i.e. they can be accessed with a subset of the file API and their API's behave in the same way as the object that accesses a real file.

This is why they are called file-like because they use the same API's and act in the same way. You open, close, can read or write a pipe in the same way as you do a file.

Comment: Yes I know. But I don't have a file. First: I certainly don't require to implement all kind of methods for `requests`, as `requests` likely will only invoke one or two. Second: There's much talking about "file like objects" all around Python, but I never saw a reasonably short, clear, compact documentation. I'd be very happy if you could help me with both issues :-)

Comment: And I'm not sure what I possibly could assist tell you about the binary data. It's binary data: I have the complete size and can randomly access any kind of chunk I'd like. This is no big deal. The question is: How can I interface with `requests` as I don't have a "file like object" (yet). How do I build a suitable? I don't have enough information for that.